# ROS installation not complete

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full

ros groovy desktop full install is not getting completing..
After completing till 70% it gives an error that internet connection problem every time while my internet connection is quite good.
I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61680/ros-installation-not-complete/) by [Atal  Ashutosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4778/atal--ashutosh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-04-27**:
Stops always in the same place?

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-04-28**:
In your 'software sources', check if the download location is set to a server close to your current location. If not, set it accordingly and re-try.

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2013-04-28**:
What hardware are you installing this on?

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-04-29**:
Are you sure the installation stops on a package from the ros repository? Which package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If it always stops on the same package it is likely that there is already a new version of that package and the old one can not be downloaded anymore.
Try running "sudo apt-get update" again.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2